# Showing that $X$ is locally compact and locally metrizable.

Tags: general-topology

Showing that $X$ is locally compact and locally metrizable, where $X$ is a space that is locally
$m$-euclidean.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially immediate since the properties are local and possessed by Euclidean space.

For any point $p \in X$ let $U \simeq \mathbb{R}^m$ be a Euclidean neighbourhood of $p$. Then $U$ is metrizable since $\mathbb{R}^m$ is, and any Euclidean closed ball around $p$ gives a compact neighbourhood.